# c++ overload operator==

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have a class with the following

```
bool DistinctWord::operator==(const DistinctWord W) const
{
    return strWord == W.strWord;
}
bool DistinctWord::operator==(const DistinctWord& W) const 
{
    return strWord == W.strWord;
}
```

I'm doing this in my program

```
    DistinctWord* wordOne = new DistinctWord("Test");
    DistinctWord* wordTwo = new DistinctWord("Test");

    if(*wordOne == *wordTwo)
        cout << "true";
    else
        cout << "false";
```

I get this error

error C2678: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'DistinctWord' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
        could be 'built-in C++ operator==(DistinctWord *, DistinctWord *

)'

I'm probably just not understanding the right way to overload.

Sorry for the simple question. TIA

Comment: What is `Word`'s inheritance tree?

Comment: What type is `strWord`? Also, does it give you a specific line for the error?

Comment: @Jeremiah: see my latest (on the top) edit. It has the solution you need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT:**

OK, I've figured out your problem. It is the non-reference version of the `operator==`. It makes the `operator==` ambiguous. Simply remove it (as I originally suggested) and it'll work fine.

---

**EDIT:**

In response to your edit, you should still remove the first version of the `operator==` There is no need to make a copy of the object in question and then compare it. The second `operator==` looks reasonable and should work. Is there anything else you are leaving out?

---

**EDIT:**

The following compiles just fine for me using g++ 4.4.1:

```
#include <iostream>

struct DistinctWord {
    DistinctWord(const std::string &s) : strWord(s){}

    bool operator==(const DistinctWord& W) const {
        return strWord == W.strWord;
    }

    std::string strWord;
};


int main() {
    DistinctWord* wordOne = new DistinctWord("Test");
    DistinctWord* wordTwo = new DistinctWord("Test");

    if(*wordOne == *wordTwo)
        std::cout << "true";
    else
        std::cout << "false";
}
```

If you are still having problems, then you are not showing all relevant code...

---

First of all, where is the definition for `DistinctWord` and how does it relate to `Word`?

Beyond that, you should do this:

```
bool Word::operator==(const Word& W) const {
     return strWord == W.strWord;
}
```

and just remove the two `operator==`'s you currently have. The first is making a copy then comparing which is silly, and your second is comparing a modifiable reference and always returning true which doesn't really serve any purpose.

This one should work fine.

Comment: Edit show what I have now.  Error still there

The reason for two methods is so I can pass by reference or by value.  I just placed return true in there for testing purposes.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why do you wish to pass by value? The only useful things to pass should be allowed by the const ref version.

Comment: Yours works for me in a new project, but not in my current one.  I'm going to go thru and see what I can find.  I'll post back in a bit with the results.  Thanks

Comment: I went back and rewrote my main.  Works now.

Thanks for all the quick help.